Some Applicatons not visible over RDP
I am running Ubuntu Desktop v 24.04.1 LTS. I remote into this machine from a Windows 10 computer using the standard Microsoft RDP client. On the Ubuntu side, I have enabled the remote login option.
Some applications work fine, such as Firefox that I am posting from now. However, other applications like Settings, File Explorer, and Text Editor do not display when opened. I can see that the applications are open; there is a red dot to the left of their icon and when I use the ALT+TAB shortcut, their icons display, but no window itself.
I know it did work correctly on 9/2/24, but since 9/10/24 it has not. I do not remember making any software updates since then.
